# Open remote git repository from command line

Tags: macos, bash, git

I'm using git on a Mac, and I'd like to know if there's a command to open the remote repository (origin) in a browser from the terminal.

Comment: "Open" certainly isn't a git technical term...

Comment: Right. I added the "in a browser" to clarify

Comment: For example, the equivalent with Heroku would be `heroku open`

Comment: The remote repository is the URL with `.git`, e.g. `git@github.com:slhck/foo.git`, so how'd you map this to whatever HTML representation there is? Are you talking about a special repository like GitHub only, or… ?

Comment: At least with Github, the URLs that come up when I run `git remote -v` seem to be accessible when plugged into a browser. I guess this wouldn't apply in all situations, though.

Comment: As far as dirty hacks go, I found that the following works when proper URLs come up with `git remote -v`:`$ git remote -v | awk '/origin.*push/ {print $2}' | xargs open`

Comment: @chrisf, "opening the git repo in the browser" works _only_ if the remote repository is set up to be accessed by HTTP, for example by http://gitorious.org or by the (quite limited) HTTP server that comes bundled with git itself.

Comment: @vonbrand I was mainly referring to remote repo services like Github or Bitbucket that have web-accessible pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t view the remote repository in a browser as the browser requires a web server.

What you can do though is clone the remote repository (if you haven't done so already) and then run the `git instaweb` command in the directory  of the local repository, which will let you browse the history, branches, commits, diffs.

Comment: I like that. Not quite what I was talking about, but perhaps this is a preferable alternative.

Answer (score 9):

There's a [github project](https://github.com/paulirish/git-open) allowing you to open git repository in your browser with `git open` command. It supports various remote repositories (not only GitHub, but also Gitlab, Bitbucket and others) and works also in cases where `git remote -v` returns URL in a `git@...` format.

Answer (score 5):

It's kind of ugly, and will only work in a few cases, but I came up with a way that works for me.

```
$ git remote -v | awk '/origin.*push/ {print $2}' | xargs open
```

I then assigned that to the alias `gitrm`. I'm not sure if `open` works on anything besides OSX, though.

In the end I realized that not every remote repository has a friendly web-based frontend, so it wouldn't really make sense for git to provide a command to open them.

Comment: For those of you who are slow to remember about escaping your alias commands, let me remind you to escape the $: `alias gitrm="git remote -v | awk '/origin.*push/ {print \$2}' | xargs open"`

Comment: ha, this is exactly what happened to me when I made this alias, thanks Michael 

Answer (score 4):

If your remote output is something like this:

```
origin  git@github.abc.xyz.com:opp/wee.git (fetch)
```

```
git remote -v | head -n 1 | awk -F "@" '{print $2}' | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | sed 's/:/\//g' | sed 's/.git//g' | awk '{print "http://"$1}' | xargs open
```

will open `http://github.abc.xyz.com/opp/wee` in the browser. I haven't come across other remote outputs, so hopefully this works mostly.

Comment: this is the only one that works with arbitrary ssh remotes.  I'd update `http` to `https` though

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 4):

I made this little bash function for what you need.

```bash
function gbrowse {
    gbrowsevar=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
    printf "${gbrowsevar}"
    start $gbrowsevar
}
```

Add it to your local file `.bashrc`, usually at the home folder in any OS. Then use it from the bash command line just by typing in `gbrowse`.

The third line inside the function will open the remote repository using the default browser. If you want a custom one, do instead something like `start firefox $gbrowsevar`

By the way, you need to be in your local repo (at any folder level below works the same, as far as I tested it).

Usage example (it will open in the last window you used):

[image]

By the way, that repository I used in the example is public, and you can find some files I find useful, including a copy of my `.bashrc` file (`worspaces-and-settings` folder), with some useful git commands in it (I'm still working in it though).

### Bonus

For Windows systems.

```bash
# GIT: open remote repository using Google Chrome
function gbrowse {
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color
    SB='\033[1;34m' # Sky Blue
    PP='\033[1;35m' # Purple
    gbrowsevar=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
    printf "\n${PP}→ ${SB}gbrowse:${NC} Chrome\n"
    printf "${gbrowsevar}\n"
    start chrome $gbrowsevar
}

# GIT: open remote repository using Firefox
function fbrowse {
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color
    SB='\033[1;34m' # Sky Blue
    PP='\033[1;35m' # Purple
    fbrowsevar=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
    printf "\n${PP}→ ${SB}fbrowse:${NC} Firefox\n"
    printf "${fbrowsevar}\n"
    start firefox $fbrowsevar
}
```

[How do you change the color scheme in bash on Ubuntu for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1114549/how-do-you-change-the-color-scheme-in-bash-on-ubuntu-for-windows)

Comment: The question is 8 years and 9 months old.

Comment: @Toto Why are you here then? Google this: `open git repository from terminal in browser`

Comment: NOTE: I've found that this function does not work with some local repositories. I think that it works only in public repos (but not really sure yet).

Comment: this assumes https, not SSH url

Comment: @Urchin I don't have experience using SSH. Any idea how to implement it in this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a cli ([to-where-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-where-cli)) that can help you solve this problem, just execute:

```
npm install -g to-where-cli
// open current remote branch
tw git open 
// open master/main remote branch
tw git open -m
```

github: https://github.com/skypesky/to-where-cli

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-where-cli

Answer (score 0):

Quick alias to be placed in `.zshrc`/`.bashrc`.

```sh
alias remote='open "$(git remote get-url origin | sed "s/\.git$//")"'
```

**Note**: `open` is designed for files/dirs/URLs on MacOS. Linux users may need to substitute with `xdg-open`.