# How do you change the color scheme in bash on Ubuntu for Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've tried to create color schemes with https://terminal.sexy and http://ciembor.github.io/4bit/ but I can't get any of their exports to work with bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

What's the correct approach to customize the colors in boUoW?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is not specific to bash on Ubuntu for Windows, as the terminal is still provided by `conhost.exe`.

To change the colors, you can go into the **Defaults**:

[image]

And then you can click each individual color and change it to some other color.

[image]

The process is somewhat confusing, because by clicking a color rectangle, you're changing what is selected as the **Screen Background**. So you first have to change that selection, adjust the color and then change the selection back to your desired background color.

Overall, it is easier to just go with a different terminal or console emulator altogether. I personally use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) now, which allows you to change color schemes much easier.

Comment: Setting `Screen Text` to black (0,0,0) and `Screen Background` to some sort of light yellow (255,255,150) has worked pretty well for me. See [sample screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/zkAhq).

Comment: The terminal is not, and has never been, provided by cmd.exe. The console was provided directly by csrss from NT through XP, and then conhost.exe since Vista. Bash runs directly via conhost and never touches cmd.

Comment: @YiboYang close to your suggestion, there is (255, 255, 221), which is the "black on light yellow" theme from Gnome terminal.

Answer (score 39):

This is also a nice and easy solution, from https://medium.com/@iraklis/fixing-dark-blue-colors-on-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-c6b009f8b97c :

Append this to `.bashrc`:

```
LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=1;35:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';
export LS_COLORS

PS1='\e[37;1m\u@\e[35m\W\e[0m\$ ' # this will change your prompt format
```

And I found this useful too for vim's readability:

```
echo "set background=dark" >> .vimrc
```

Comment: But it doesn't explain what any of those parameters are.  Since I want to specify different colors, this isn't really useful for doing that except by trial and error.

Comment: what is the definition syntax of these colors? For example, how do you change the color palette for directories? And for other stuff defined in here?

Comment: I mean, I get why this is not the chosen answer, but I confess that it serves me well. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 10):

2019 Solution:

The official [ColorTool](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal/tree/master/src/tools/ColorTool) from Microsoft can be used to change the overall color scheme without having to set each color by yourself.

Just download the zip file (search for `Color Tool <Month> <Year>` under [Releases](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases)) and extract the tool to any folder. Then run it from your bash:

```
# run in wsl bash (or any other windows terminal)
# note that -x is required for wsl
./ColorTool.exe -x <scheme name>

# for the change to have permanent effect go to properties and click ok
```

Then you can easily import other color schemes in the iTerm format, by placing a `.itermcolors` file in the `schemes` folder of the ColorTool.

Comment: This was the cleanest, simplest, and easiest solution for me. Also I can understand what's going on, and change it later, which is a plus. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the new Windows Terminal is supposed to be good for solving this problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal

Answer (score 7):

Same solution as the others with some more explanation for people like me (https://medium.com/@iraklis/fixing-dark-blue-colors-on-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-c6b009f8b97c)

```
cd /home/<user>
ls -a
```

You should find a .bashrc and make a BU

```
cp .bashrc .bashrcBU
```

add 2 lines

```
echo "LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=1;35:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:';" >> .bashrc
echo "export LS_COLORS" >> .bashrc
```

before change vim also background to see correctly

```
echo "set background=dark" >> .vimrc
```

quit and restart

You then still have the path in the name with this strange blue color. You can modify this via PS1. Here the source (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219125/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-font-color-of-the-current-path-in-termial)

```
echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

By me the balise *[\033[01;34m]***[\033[00m]* is the blue color so I change the color in pink *[\033[01;34m]***[\033[00m]*. To overwrite PS1

**@EDIT:**

You could do it this way, but it will not be permanent, and this variable will be deleted at the end of the session.

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[00m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'
```

To make it permanent you have to write it to a file that will be loaded at the beginning of a session, like the precedent .bashrc.

```
echo "PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;35m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$'" >> .bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You save my life-time with this simple explanation

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the UI lets you change all ANSI colors, you'd have to edit them via the registry.

There is already a solarized-dark theme that works quite well on https://github.com/neilpa/cmd-colors-solarized

(close/open the console window to activate)

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows cmd's color customization to customize boW. Simply click on the small ubuntu icon in top right corner and click properties.

Also, to customize the prompt, you can use

```
export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "
```

which will change only the prompt to red and so on.

As such, colors seem to work fine on boW. The above sites won't work as they create config files for specific terminal emulators, but its just cmd here.

Comment: The Properties dialog allows me to set foreground and background color, but not the color scheme. Unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Okay, you *can* adjust the color scheme that way. You have to select a color from the palette, adjust the RGB, then go to the next one and then finally select what background color you want again. Your answer could have been a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

Also looking for a solution, found this SuperUser post then this post from MS [Understanding Windows Console Host Settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/06/20/understanding-windows-console-host-settings/)

What it basically amounts to is all the settings are stored in the Shortcut file itself upon creation in the Start menu / Pinned to taskbar. Which can then be changed by modifying the properties.

Everything including colors can be customized in registry entry [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\Git Bash] using properties outlined in the MS post, but to realize the change bash.exe must be executed directly by running "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" via Windows+R to force Windows to stop reading config in after the registry entries.

Once satisfied with the config, create new shortcut links in start and pin-to taskbar (if that's your thing).

Argument for doing it this way, is sweeping changes are easier to manage (say a new color scheme try out?) through .reg file than through tedious making and saving changes to a shortcut file.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the correct approach to customize the colors in boUoW?

As others have mentioned, .bashrc is usually your goto for adding the code.

The colors operate on '[escape sequences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-160)'.  e.g. the sequence for Light Blue is \033[1;34m

[The Linux Command Line](https://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) book covers in detail changing color and format of prompt.
Chapter 13: Custominzing The Prompt: Adding Color pg. 183

"Released under a Creative Commons license, this book is available for free download in PDF format."

Highly reccomended reading/reference for those who want to know more of the 'why' behind the CLI.

***Alternatively*** :

It has some baked in color in the .bashrc if you uncomment a line, remove the '#' symbol.
Line 39: #force_color_prompt=yes

Either modify this file in Ubuntu nano or similar editor.  Or using Windows, navigate to the folder (CAUTION: you can potentially screw things up in here.)
C:\Users\"YourUserName"\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\root

and open the .bashrc file using Vim, emacs, notepad++, etc, to edit.  Usually best to avoid using Windows Notepad, has been know to cause problems in the past.